# Windows 7, Conexant High Def Audio drivers not working on Lenovo R61i

Tags: windows-7, audio, thinkpad, sound-card

I just installed Windows 7 ultimate on my Lenovo ThinkPad R61i. Driver update says I have the latest version installed but there is no sound from the loudspeakers. My question is: **What can I do to get the sound working?** Everything else works fine.

I have searched and asked questions on Lenovo forums but still no answers.

Comment: Did you use Lenovo System Upgrade for upgrading to the latest sound driver?

Comment: Yes. I actually downloaded the latest Win7 soundcard drivers for conexant high def audio from their site. And it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well I wouldn't use that, I use only drivers provided and tested out by Lenovo. It installed a driver from the software manager and works perfectly. :/ Without the driver  ? Does it work?

Comment: No it doesn't work and the drivers are from Lenovo's website.

Comment: Without them? I mean basically after you install the vanilla Windows 7?